# Randomized PHP forms

Tags: php, session, post

I have a set of 5 forms that need to be presented consecutively, but randomly, before processing the results.

For now I have created each set of questions in it's own file `formA.php`, `formB.php`... but am struggling with how best to randomize the order every time without repeating any of the forms, my best guess is to create a `$randomizedForms = array('formA.php','formB.php'...);` and then `shuffle` it, but how I lead from one form to the next, and keep the order every time is eluding me.

Comment: before the first step, create the shuffling, on an array, then save the order on a session so that you can keep it and use that sequence on the next stages

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
echo '<pre>';
$randomizedForms = array('formA.php', 'formB.php', 'formC.php', 'formD.php', 'formE.php');
print_r($randomizedForms);
$defaultForms = $randomizedForms;
foreach($randomizedForms as $form){
    shuffle($randomizedForms);
    $get = array_shift($randomizedForms);
    print_r($randomizedForms);echo '<br>';
    print_r($get);echo '<br>';
}
echo '</pre>';
?>
```

Comment: I'm not having a problem with the randomizing. I need to have each form presented sequentially (so that when they hit submit on the first form, it takes them to the next random form).